# Why should we prefer negated character classes to .* in regexes?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I was looking at a tutorial on Regex.

It was about how to get the class attribute from this piece of html

```
<pre class="ruby" name="code">
```

and the regex used was

```
<pre class="([^"]+)" name="code">
```

They recommended to use the above one instead of

```
<pre class="(.+)" name="code">
```

"as it goes beyond the quote."

I don't understand what they mean. It is just going to work anyway but then why the first regex is recommended. Am I missing anything? Please enlighten me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Blender, see my answer re: `(.*?)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.+` matches greedily. for example, in

```
<pre class="ruby" size="medium" name="code">
```

it would match `ruby" size="medium`. Even worse, if you had two tags on the same line, it would match right across the tag boundaries:

```
<pre class="ruby" name="code">foo</pre> <pre class="python" name="code">bar</pre>
```

would result in `ruby" name="code">foo</pre> <pre class="python`!

So as long as you know exactly what your HTML will look like, `.+` can work, but as soon as it changes unexpectedly (as HTML is wont to do), your regex wouldn't simply fail (as the second one would) but it would match the wrong stuff.

Therefore, the second regex is safer (since it's more explicit about what exactly is allowed to match). You usually should try and avoid the simple `.+` or `.*` "match anything", and instead think about what you do want to match.

That said, for precisely the same reasons, you shouldn't try and match HTML and other markup languages with regexes anyway because there are better tools for that.

Comment: OMG! I got it now. Thanks for the example. BTW They were just using that html text as some example for explaining Regex. Not seriously to get the class attribute. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Regex matching normally attempts to match the longest regex it can. Therefore "([^"]+)" only matches up to the *first* quote it encounters. On the other hand, "(.+)" will match from the first quote to the very *last* quote in the string.

For example, if we applied them to your question, the first would match `"ruby"`, because that's the first quoted string in your question. The second would match all the way from `"ruby` on through `beyond the quote"`, because that's the last quote in the question (and would include several other quoted strings in between.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```
<pre class="scooby" name="not-code">
  content
</pre>

...other HTML...

<pre class="ruby" name="code">
  content
</pre>
```

With this regex [*]:

```
<pre class="(.+)" name="code">
```

...the first part - `<pre class="` - starts matching the first tag, then the `(.+)` consumes the entire rest of the document.  But the rest of the regex - `" name="code">` - can't match there, so it backs off until it finds a position where it can--in the second tag.  Result: the group ends up capturing everything from `scooby` to `ruby`.

This will be true even if you use a non-greedy `(.+?)` instead of the greedy `(.+)`.  People often say non-greedy quantifiers cause the regex return the shortest possible match, but that's not true.  Like a greedy regex, it *starts* matching at the first opportunity; it just *stops* matching as soon as it can, too.  Situations like this one, where non-greedy quantifiers do no good, are not rare.

Another thing to think about is when there's no match possible--for example, if there are `<pre>` tags with first attribute `class="~whatever~"`, but none with a `name="code"` attribute.  At each one, the greedy `(.+)` will gobble up the whole document, then back off until it reaches its starting point before giving up.  The non-greedy `(.+?)` won't backtrack, but it will scan the whole page, and it will do it much more slowly (it effectively does a lookahead for `" name="code">` at each position).

With this regex:

```
<pre class="([^"]+)" name="code">
```

...it never has to scan beyond the end of the tag to decide if it matches.

*Always* think about what will happen if no match is possible.  That's probably the most common oversight regex authors make, and the one that causes the most performance problems.

[*] I'm assuming the match is being performed in DOTALL mode (a.k.a. single-line mode) for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Negating a class is usually much more specific about what you want to match, and can help protect against situations like [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Jeff Atwood wrote an interesting [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html) about it a while ago where he gives an example of a seemingly innocent looking regex: `(x+x+)+y` that can take (almost) forever to finish processing. Even when the subject is tiny like this: `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

Give it a read, its really quite interesting.